# Callback function in xtend

Tags: callback, xtend

How can I call a callback function in xtend?

I am looking for something similar to the one in C. 
Example:

```java
    struct callbacks
    {
      char name[10];
      boolean (*pfState)();
    };

    static const struct callbacks call[] = {
      {"YOURS", &isOwner},
      {"OURS", &our_owner}
    };
```

So, I will just call it like this: `call[0].pfState()`.

I have created a similar ArrayList in xtend.

```java
    val you = new youModule()
    val our = new ourModule()
    val callbacks = newArrayList('YOURS' -> you.isOwner, 'OURS' -> our.isOwnder);
```

Am I doing this correctly? How can I execute the function call in the pair?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you create a list of Pairs which map strings to the result of the method invocation, e.g. assuming `#isOwner` returns a `boolean`, your list callbacks is currently a `List<Pair<String, Boolean>>`.

Instead, you have to wrap the invocation of `#isOwner` in a lambda expression:

```
val callbacks = newArrayList(
  'YOURS' -> [| you.isOwner ],
  'OURS' -> [| our.isOwnder ]
);
```

Now, callbacks has the type `List<Pair<String, ()=>boolean>>`, or in other words: `List<Pair<String, Functions.Function0<Boolean>>>`.

Comment: I am getting an error with your implementation. 
Incompatible implicit return type. Expected java.util.ArrayList<java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
   or java.util.List<java.lang.Object>[] but was java.util.ArrayList<org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Pair<java.lang.String,
   org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Functions.Function0<java.lang.Boolean>>>

What's the | and [] for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "callback" stored in a variable, you need to invoke the function by calling `apply` on it.

Here is a simple example showing a hash map that contains two callbacks stored under 'YOURS' and 'OURS' key. When called, each callback function prints a different message and returns a boolean value.

```java
    val callbacks = newHashMap(
      'YOURS' -> [| println("calling the first callback");  true  ],
      'OURS'  -> [| println("calling the second callback"); false ]
    )

    val result = callbacks.get("YOURS").apply

// result is: true
// console output is: calling the first callback
```